# How can I create a stream in RxJava2 (Android) that has no input value, but produces a String?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

In Android, I want to use the call `AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getContext()).getId()` on a separate thread (IO-thread) and handle the string on the main thread.

I wan't to do this with RxJava2.
This is what I have now: (which works)

```
SingleOnSubscribe<String> source = new SingleOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(SingleEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
            e.onSuccess(AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getContext()).getId());
        }
    };

    Single.create(source)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Timber.e(throwable.getMessage());
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
                    advertisingId = s;
                }
            });
```

What I would prefer, which is purely taste, is if I could "just" create the stream and handle it all in the flow of methods. Such as: (warning, super pseudo code)

```
Completable
    .empty()
    .produce(() -> String {
        return makeString();
    })
    .sub/obs-On()...
    .subscribe(coolString -> {mVariable = coolString})
```

So, Make an Observable and turn it into an Observable by executing some function.

Comment: Why would you want to create an empty source first when you can create a single-emitting source via `fromCallable` directly?

Comment: It does not have to be empty, it can be whatever. But I don't wan't to define, create, an object that does the actions, I want to do it in streams.
Like my first implementation I had a `Observable.just("").map(s -> {return "other string"})`
I want that syntax, but less hacky

Answer (score 1):

Just use defer or fromCallable like in this example:

```
Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        return getStuff();
    });
```

### Test

```
@Test
public void fromCallable() throws Exception {
    Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        return getStuff();
    });

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(runnable -> {
        return new Thread(runnable, "myFancyThread");
    });
    Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(executorService);

    TestObserver<String> test = stringObservable.subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .test();

    test.await()
            .assertResult("wurst");

    assertThat(test.lastThread().getName()).contains("myFancyThread");
}

private String getStuff() {
    return "wurst";
}
```